# Taxonomy page - replace 404 with "No results found"

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, taxonomy

I'd like to "fake" the taxonomy page to behave like a search.

Right now if you land on localhost/search-images/**deadendtag**/page/2/ you get a 404 not found.

I'd simply like to replace that with page that says "No results" as if a search. That way its not mistaken as a ...mistake. :D

Comment: why not use javascript when you land on a certain page append to the body "No Results" ?

Comment: I could if I had to. I was wondering if making another page a default instead of 404 was possible, or even better, writing a conditional statement right in the taxonomy-image-tags.php itself to say no results.

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp-content/theme open your current theme than open 404.php and change it from there

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to modify the 404 page to change states based on if this taxonomy. So it can return any content I designate and change the title as well through a filter.

```
function filter_404_title( $title )
{
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title = 'No results found.';
    }
    // You can do other filtering here, or
    // just return $title
    return $title;
}

// Hook into wp_title filter hook
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_404_title' );


if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'image' ) {

    //my fake no-results-found content

} else {

    //the usual 404

}
```

If there is a way to go directly to the **taxonomy-image-tags.php** to obtain a "no results" statement though that would be ideal.